# What's the difference between a contract based wallet and the main account in the wallet?

Tags: ethereum

I have recently downloaded the GUI wallet, and it gives the option to create contract based wallets and connect to them to a main account. What is the difference between using a contract based wallet and an account? And what should be used to store my ether?

Answer (score 1):

Contract-based wallets are more robust and can be more secure. For example, a contract can be setup to require transfers over a certain threshold to be approved my multiple people/keys. Even if these keys all reside on your local computer, having to compromise even a slightly-improved 2 of 3 can provide far greater security than a single key alone.

Additionally, contracts benefit from transaction receipts, which contain a permanent log of all events. This makes it much easier to inspect the state and verify the history of a contract. For example, when a new transaction request is initiated against a wallet contract requiring multiple signatures, an event log for "ConfirmationNeeded" with the operation ID will be added. After the operation has received the appropriate number of signatures, a "MultiTransact" might occur containing the recipient, value, and associated data with the transaction.

Standard accounts benefit from none of this and can only send transactions, not respond autonomously.

Answer (score 0):

Here are advantages and disadvantages for comparison.

**Advantages of contract-based account wallets:**

- Funds are not stored on a single key.
- You can cycle through management keys.
- Mutisig functionality; only execute a transaction on majority rule (eg. Gnosis Multisig)
- Allows for account recovery, in case your management keys are lost (eg. Argent).
- Set transfer and withdraw limits enforced by the contract.
- You can have access controls for keys, meaning you can restrict what methods a key can invoke. Useful when you want to delegate control to someone else but restrict what they can do.
- Batched transactions; execute multiple transactions as 1 atomic transaction.
- Defi protocol composition; easily integrate with other smart contracts (eg. one-click DAI saving rate accounts)
- Meta transactions: pay your transaction costs using a different asset, like a token (eg. Gas Station Network). Relayers may also offer free transactions (eg. Authereum)

**Disadvantages of contract-based account wallets:**

- Contract are susceptible to attacks; people write buggy code all the time (eg. Parity hack). An Externally-owned account (EOA) can't be hacked because there is no code to hack.
- Backward incompatible features may render funds locked if contract not properly written. (eg. Istanbul hardfork gas cost changes)
- Deployment costs; unlikes key pairs which doesn't cost anything to generate, there's a fee cost for deploying contract-based accounts.